# What is the standard way of initializing a boolean vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I have researched around but haven't found any clear answer.

How do I initialize a boolean vector of a particular size all set to either true or false?

Comment: #2 here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, these documentations are a bit vague to me right now. Does the size_type refer to the vector size or the data type? and what does the alloc() do? I am still new to programming. I haven't yet studied to that extent.

Comment: `size_type` is a datatype large enough to hold any `vector` index that is valid for the vector implementation. These days it's typically an unsigned 64 bit integer. `alloc` is an optional parameter. It allows you to specify how the `vector` creates new elements when they are added. The [documentation page for Allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) is a serious mind freak, but you aren't likely to be messing around with custom allocators unless you get into game engine programming or embedded systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will uniformly initialize the vector:

```
const size_t SIZE = 10; // However many elements you want in the vector.
const bool initial_value = false; // All elements will be set to this value
std::vector<bool> m_allFalse(SIZE, initial_value);
```

General,
to initialize boolean values at the beginning, you can use this:

```
bool temp[] = { true, false, false, true };
std::vector<bool> variousBool ( temp, temp + sizeof(tempBool) / sizeof(bool) );
```

Comment: Or simply `std::vector<bool> variousBool = { true, false, false, true };`

Comment: @OnomeSotu that's not valid c++ as far as I know.

Comment: @chris thanks. What if I want a vector of say 100 bool values? is there a way to make this? Tasosxak's answer looks plausible but I don't understand what is the purpose of `(*)` in the statement.

Comment: @xaxxon, do you know a valid way I can do this?

Comment: @OnomeSotu, My comment applies to the second form, and correct, it's not appropriate when they're all the same value. `(*)` is an error.

Comment: std::vector<bool> foo;
foo.push_back(true or false); // you can use push_back() in loop